# save all ohai information from selected nodes

Tags: chef

I'm running the open source version of chef server 12.

While reading some docs I came across [ohai](https://docs.chef.io/ohai.html), which collects information on each node and - as far as I understand - provides this information to clientside-running code, i.e. recipes and providers.

Is there any way to save all ohai information during chef-client runs (for all nodes of a specific role), so it can be queried with knife from all or a specific node? Currently only a few information like ip address is available when searching for nodes and through node information.

Comment: You can query this information from the chef server (the usual attributes). Would this be sufficient?

Comment: @StephenKing yes, I want to query this from the chef server. My problem is that currently only a few attributes are shown, not all of them (i.e. all attributes that are shown if I run `ohai` on the client by hand). How would I do this?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. All the so called _automatic_ attributes that are set by _ohai_ are saved on the chef server by default.

Comment: @StephenKing yes, and I do to save *all* attributes to the server, not only the *automatic attributes*

Comment: But you want the attributes from _ohai_ - these are by definition _automatic_. Have you read the [docs about attributes](https://docs.chef.io/attributes.html)? There are a couple of tricky aspects..

Comment: @StephenKing yes, I think I do understand the docs, but I don't find any information on how to add something. Let's consider an example: If I run *ohai* by hand it lists the total amount of memory. This is not an automatic attribute, but I want to collect this information on all nodes, so I can query this information from a specific node as well as search for all nodes having a certain amount of total memory. How would I do this? Can I add it as an automatec attribute?

Comment: Sure, [extending ohai](https://docs.chef.io/ohai_custom.html) allows you to do this.

Comment: @StephenKing okay, I'll have a look at it, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All node attributes are always saved back up to the server after a successful converge. These don't all display in `knife node show` because it focuses on just a few frequently-used attributes. You can always display the full node JSON with `knife node show --format json --long`, but searches already run on the full dataset.